# knitr & vim: Creating *.Rnw files

Tags: vim, latex, knitr

I'm trying to get knitr using, whilst creating a *.Rnw file using Vim (with the Vim-LaTeX plugin).

If I open a *.Rnw file in Vim, and type a `<` (e.g. for `<<foo, echo=TRUE>>=`) so I can input a code chunk, I find myself unable to type it, and Vim returns an error 'E117: Unknown function: RwriteChunk'

I have no problems typing a `>`or writing inline code (`\Sexpr{}`). Anyone found any solutions to this problem?

Many thanks,
Tom

---

## PROBLEM RESOLVED

It turns out that the necessary runtime file wasn't in the right place. I have copied it from  "~/.vim/ftplugin" to "/usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin" and now everything is working fine.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's quite OK to answer your own question here. That way, the question is marked as answered and resolved, and it'll be easier for people in the future to find the answer if they face a similar issue.